# Cannot Login when Using Middleware Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I had a problem with my Laravel Authentication. I cannot redirect to the page that supposed to go when I'm logging in. Hence, it would redirect back again to my login page when I'm using middleware. I am using middleware because it is a multiple authentication type.

Web.php Routes

```
Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::get('/inbox', 'HomeController@nonadmin')->middleware('admin')->name('inbox');

    //Route::get('/department', 'DepartmentController@index');
    Route::resource('department', 'DepartmentController');
    Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');
    Route::resource('faculty', 'FacultyController');
    Route::resource('student', 'StudentController');
    //Route::get('logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');
    Auth::logout();
});
```

Admin.php middleware

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth; 

class Admin
{
   /**
       * Handle an incoming request.
       *
       * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
       * @param  \Closure  $next
       * @return mixed
       */
   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
   {
       if (!Auth::check()) {
           return redirect()->route('login');
       }

       if(Auth::user()->user_type == 'Admin' &&  Auth::user()->status == 'Active')
       {
           return redirect()->route('dashboard');
       }
       
       if(Auth::user()->user_type == 'Staff' &&  Auth::user()->status == 'Active')
       {
           return redirect()->route('dashboard');
       }

       if(Auth::user()->user_type == 'Faculty' &&  Auth::user()->status == 'Active')
       {
           return redirect()->route('inbox');
       }
       
       if(Auth::user()->user_type == 'Student' &&  Auth::user()->status == 'Active')
       {
           return redirect()->route('inbox');
       }

       if(Auth::user()->user_type == 'Parent' &&  Auth::user()->status == 'Active')
       {
           return redirect()->route('inbox');
       }
   }
}
```

LoginController

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
    * Where to redirect users after login.
    *
    * @var string
    */
protected $redirectTo = '/';

/**
    * Create a new controller instance.
    *
    * @return void
    */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}

public function logout(Request $request) {
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect('/');
}

public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

I also declare the middleware in Kernel.php I use this on my previous projects. But on this current one where I use Laravel 7 the current version, it all redirects on a login page.

Update:

I updated the routes as suggestion by Qirel.

```
Auth::routes();
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->middleware('admin')->name('home');
    Route::get('/inbox', 'HomeController@nonadmin')->name('inbox');

    //Route::get('/department', 'DepartmentController@index');
    Route::resource('department', 'DepartmentController');
    Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');
    Route::resource('faculty', 'FacultyController');
    Route::resource('student', 'StudentController');
});
```

And I also put the `return $next($request);` on the middleware on the last part still not working. I wondering that in my current project, it is not working but on the past it is working.

Comment: `Auth::logout();` means "*log me out now*". You probably want `Auth::routes(['only' => 'logout']);` But you don't need this, since you declare `Auth::routes()` up top.

Comment: Qirel is right. Also your `Admin` middleware looks kind of strange. You don't return `next` in case that you don't redirect? Also you could maybe put `if(Auth::user()->status != 'Active') return $next;` at the top, then you don't have to check it for the other 5 if statments.

Comment: The reason why I use middleware is I had a multiple authentication. Example if it is an admin it will redirect to admin page and if it is a staff, it will proceed to staff page

Comment: but you have no way to actually reach the route that the middleware is assigned to ... you have to `return $next($request);` at some point to let the request pass through

Comment: Still not work after I code the ```return $next($request);```

Answer (score 0):

In your routes, you've got

```php
Auth::logout();
```

..which it appears you've added because you think it adds the logout-route for you. That method actually will attempt to *log the user out!* - it does not add any routes. What currently happens is that whenever any user is authenticated, it will render the routes in that group, and then log them out, thereby making it impossible to log in.

Your solution is simply to remove `Auth::logout()` from your routes.

To add the logout route explicitly, you need to add

```php
Auth::routes(['only' => 'logout']);
```

However, you don't need to do that - as you already included all the auth-routes by adding `Auth::routes()` at the top, which handles it all for you.

Comment: I remove ```Auth::logout()``` in my routes is still the same sir. I still redirect in login form.

Answer (score 0):

**Step-1**

You write below function in your admin.php middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
   {
       if (!Auth::check()) {
           return redirect()->route('login');
       }

       if(Auth::user()->user_type == 'Admin' &&  Auth::user()->status == 'Active')
       {
           return redirect()->route('dashboard');
       }
       
       if(Auth::user()->user_type == 'Staff' &&  Auth::user()->status == 'Active')
       {
           return redirect()->route('dashboard');
       }

       if(Auth::user()->user_type == 'Faculty' &&  Auth::user()->status == 'Active')
       {
           return redirect()->route('inbox');
       }
       
       if(Auth::user()->user_type == 'Student' &&  Auth::user()->status == 'Active')
       {
           return redirect()->route('inbox');
       }

       if(Auth::user()->user_type == 'Parent' &&  Auth::user()->status == 'Active')
       {
           return redirect()->route('inbox');
       }
   }
```

So it will not woek becuase at same time it check login+role+status so when any one need to login so it has not active status.

SO Please Replace that function with below code

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
   {
       if (!Auth::check()) {
           return redirect()->route('login');
       }

       if(Auth::user()->user_type == 'Admin')
       {
           return redirect()->route('dashboard');
       }
       
       if(Auth::user()->user_type == 'Staff' )
       {
           return redirect()->route('dashboard');
       }

       if(Auth::user()->user_type == 'Faculty')
       {
           return redirect()->route('inbox');
       }
       
       if(Auth::user()->user_type == 'Student')
       {
           return redirect()->route('inbox');
       }

       if(Auth::user()->user_type == 'Parent' )
       {
           return redirect()->route('inbox');
       }
   }
```

**Step-2**

In your logincontroller.php you write,

```
   public function logout(Request $request) {
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect('/');
}

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
```

so please remove that function and paste below line in logincontroller.php

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');   
    }
```

Now it will redirect to the '/' route or the route you wanted.

Comment: still not working for me sir. same issues especially in ```$this->middleware('auth');``` part of the code no login page is appearing

Comment: maybe you have version issue please try to update laravel version maybe it will then work.

Comment: my laravel version is the latest one, Laravel 7

Comment: You can follow link of laravel offical website to update it https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade